# Preventing tilt from calling onCreate, and time measurement of an activity running.

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

Hi and thanks in advance for your time and attention.
I actually have 2 questions i'm not too sure about building an android app. Pretty basic stuff I believe:

1) My app is fully on Horizontal mode, like AngryBirds for example. When it starts the user figures out he should hold the phone like that, if he isn't already. And that is setup in the manifest for all the activities and works fine. but is there a way to prevent the physical device tilting to call onCreate again? can i override it's method or whatever? the reason i'm asking, is because i have a few ButtonViews that after you click on them, change their picture. i am using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to save the array of those ImageButtons, and i even mark the ones changed with the ImageButton setTag() and getTag() methods, so when onCreate is called because of the device tilt it gets the saved array from getLastNonConfigurationInstance() , but i've been trying to make it work for quite some time now and I just can't get it right. After the device tilt (I'm actually using the emulator so it's Ctrl+F11 but i believe it will happen with a device as well) all of the ImageButtons loose their pictures.. Long story short - are there better ways of doing this that you can recommend or is preventing the tilt from doing anything is possible or better?

2) What is the best way to know how many seconds the user has been on a screen? I tried to use two longs that i get via SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() as follows: get the starting time onCreate, and the ending time on the method i call to move to the second intent just before i startActivity. but I think because they are called from different threads, the endingpoint - startingpoint is not correct. What is the way to insure both of the methods of SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis() are called from the same thread, the main thread of the activity that i'm stopwatching? Is there a better way to go around this?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are doing the right to handle orientation change. Please refer to this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html . This will help you to get it working.
2. Good way would be to count the time between onResume and onPause. OnCreate is not called all the time if you are resuming activity.

Comment: 1. i've tried to do exactly as that example with those 2 methods. Is that what you meant?

Comment: 2. Sorry for the ignorance but why doesn't eclipse auto completes me when typing onPause CTRL+Space and onResume CTRL+Space? How do i override those in an activity?

Comment: Yes, it should def. work. If you could paste the code in your question then someone can help you in identifying what you doing wrong.

Comment: For auto complete thing, instead you can right click on your activity class name in source file and click on source->override and implement methods and then select onResume and onPause.

Comment: Thanks. I see. How do i override those methods? Why wouldn't eclipse auto complete me and let me override onPause and onResume?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, you can heads up.

Comment: I have never found eclipse auto completing on onResume and onPause because those are not the must to have methods. If there are some must to have methods implemented then it will complain about it and then you can add or override those methods just with one click.

Comment: as i understand, i don't have enough reputation for heads up. sorry.

Comment: my point is, on an activity clicking CTRL+Space lets you see all the methods you can override or implement. i don't see onResume/onPause on the list. how so? if i'll just type private void onResume() { .. }; myself, will that do? usually this isn't the case with overriding, no?

Comment: No this is what you need to write in code  @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }

Comment: Strange enough i only see Object methods there. when clicking upper in the class page i got the right options. thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that onPause isn't ran automatically before starting another intent? i now get a negative value of seconds, after using onPause onResume methods. do i need to run onPause myself before starting the next intent?

Comment: No you do not run onPause by yourself at any time. This is in the concepts of android activity life cycle. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html. Also, every time you start another activity from current activity. The current activity pauses itself and starts new activity. You can put log statements in onPause and onResume to see if they are getting called or not.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can try adding the property `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your activity in the manifest file. It worked for me when my dynamic Action Bar tabs got messed up upon rotation of the screen.

Comment: thanks but it didn't solve the issue. I've added this property and now the activity looks like this in the manifast: `
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:configChanges="orientation"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: without the <activity android:name=".BasicActivity" of course, i ran out of chars to reply

Answer (score 0):

1. You need specify orientation in android manifest for each of your activities, it will not call onCreate then. `android:screenOrientation` look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html
2. User see and interact with your activity starting since onResume and ends on onPause. Other time it does not guarantee that user actually see and can click on something in the activity. System.getCurrentMillis() is good enough.

Comment: android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="orientation"   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" atributes are all set in the manifest, and still what i said happens..

Comment: You do not really need android:configChanges